# How to unerase an erased UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying an image erasing code in my PanGesture. I am using the code below:

```
 UIImage * image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"326d4fb72362a2e44659141cadfc4977.jpg"];
 holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 235)];
 imgForeground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
 [imgForeground setImage:image];
 [holderView addSubview:imgForeground];


 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
 [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
 [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
 [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
 [holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
 [self.view addSubview:holderView];
```

Then I am handling this here:

```
 -(void)move:(id)sender {

    CGPoint currentPoint;
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        
        lastPoint =  [sender locationInView:imgForeground];
        lastPoint.y -=20;
    }
    else{
    
        currentPoint = [sender locationInView:imgForeground];;
        currentPoint.y -=20;
    }
   
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgForeground.frame.size);
    [imgForeground.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(imgForeground.frame.origin.x, imgForeground.frame.origin.y, imgForeground.frame.size.width, imgForeground.frame.size.height)];
    
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineCap(context,kCGLineCapRound); //kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    imgForeground.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 }
```

How to unerase the same image?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are building the image with an image context?  This doesn't exactly solve your question but I would put my image in a scrollview.  A scrollview would automatically give you scrolling if the image size is larger than viewable area.

Comment: I guess your not getting my question I am erasing the image not scrolling the image. Means when I move my finger upon image it will be removed

Comment: When you say "unerase" do you mean undo?  And if so, do you need multiple levels of undo (and I suppose redo)?

Comment: No buddy I am using a tool where user can Erase and Unerase the picture according to his need.<br> But I am not able to use unerase tool

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha i updated answer please check and let me know if u face any error or queries....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue in my app after the long search i found the simple solution for this issue.

i just used touches methods of the `UIViewController`

The below is the my approach,

**Code:-**

```
   #pragma mark touches stuff...



 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.editedImageView];
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.editedImageView];

        CGFloat brushSize;
        if (isEraser) 
        {
            brushSize=eraser;
        }
        else
        {
            brushSize=mark;
        }
        CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.editedImageView.frame.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [self.editedImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.editedImageView.frame.size.width, self.editedImageView.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushSize);
        if (isEraser) {

            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.im].CGColor);
        }  
        else
        {
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear); 
        }
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        self.editedImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.editedImageView];
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

    }
```

**The Inputs:**

```
self.editedImageView.image = "Your Custom image";

self.im    =   "Your Custom image";
```

**The simple solution of your problem will be :-**

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.im].CGColor);
```

**Note:**

This not unerase it again drawing the image over

**Update:-**

```
 self.im    =   "Your Custom image";
```

this will be like this....

```
-(void)eraserConfigure
{
    UIImageView *resizeImage=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:editedImage]autorelease];
    /*UIImage */self.im=[UIImage imageFromView:resizeImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(self.editedImageView.frame.size.width, self.editedImageView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha i hope it will help u,but it is not a  unerase

Comment: Thanks spynet This code is working only problem is....
It is taking color from area wch is -50px from there

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha sorry yar i can't get you could u elaborate so that i can understand clearly....

Comment: when I am again drawing the image over the new image draw above -50px on y axis

Comment: Check your image view type is it aspect fit or aspect fill may be this causes this issue or u just resize accordingly

Comment: No it is UIViewContentModeScaleToFill and what contentMode I should put there

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha try this i hope it will help you UIImageView *resizeImage=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:editedImage]autorelease];
    /*UIImage */self.im=[UIImage imageFromView:resizeImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(self.editedImageView.frame.size.width, self.editedImageView.frame.size.height)];

Comment: You have used two imageview here  editedImageView and resizeImage... I am confused with them

Comment: And where to call eraserConfigure?

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha don't confuse u just replace self.im    =   "Your Custom image"; this to  UIImageView *resizeImage=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:editedImage]autorelease]; /*UIImage */self.im=[UIImage imageFromView:resizeImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(self.editedImageView.frame.size.width, self.editedImageView.frame.size.height)];

Comment: This method imageFromView is not available :(

Comment: that is the image category method simple google out u can get otherwise let me know

Comment: I got this so Far is it same ?


- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

Comment: Please refer this i modified few things in the class but your method looks same if u any doubts means mail me... really i proud to help u man keep rocking Thanks for giving me 100 man

Comment: Hey dude I got another problem in same Please refer this link

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha may i know your issue man? where is the link

Comment: Neways its resolved and the link is 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729021/drawinrect-losing-quality-of-image-resolution/

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha Super nice keep rock

Answer (score 0):

Save a **temporary image** after every drawing operation.
You should save on temporary files and limit the number of undo operations.

Comment: Buddy I am looking for something Like Unerase when user move his finger around erased area..
Undo is something different

Comment: Its good technique but its may create problem in memory warning adding one image on other.I other hand yeah it may slow and lazy process due to writing and retrieving binary files on disk.