# drawInRect: losing Quality of Image resolution

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I am trying to erase image using following code

```
 CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgForeground.frame.size);

 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [imgForeground.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgForeground.frame.size.width, imgForeground.frame.size.height)];

 CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);

 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);
 CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);

 CGContextBeginPath(context);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
 CGContextStrokePath(context);

 imgForeground.image  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But I just find out Image losing its resolution due to **drawInRect**.

[image: Before]  [image: After]

Comment: Uploading the "before" and "after" screenshot images would be of great help for a question involving visuals.

Comment: Image uploaded Please refer

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "losing quality of image resolution". Perhaps you could try to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should go with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, so that a scale factor can be specified.

For example, this will use the scale factor of the device's main screen:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgForeground.frame.size, NO, 0);
```

Comment: What if image is not of size of Window?
Than what to replace with imgForeground.window.screen.scale

Comment: Hi! Well, the 3rd parameter is the scale and not any dimension (i.e. size)! For all iPhones, iPodTouches etc. that do NOT have Retina Displays it will return a 1.0f, while Retina Display devices will give a 2.0f.

Comment: replace 'imgForeground.window.screen.scale' with '[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]', so it becomes more clear that the scale of the "screen" is meant!

Comment: Third param can be simply `0`, it means that scale will be choosen automatically (usual convention in Cocoa)