# Drawing pattern with UIImage not like pattern but it is filled UIImage in UIView

Tags: iphone, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawimage

My line of code:

```
UIColor *brushPattern=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame-1@2x.png"]];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),brushPattern.CGColor);
Image pattern
```

[url](http://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/733867_513688398695514_212660265_n.jpg)

Which does not draw like brush pattern whereas it fill pattern in `UIView`

Comment: Hope code below will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following code for the same

At ViewDidLoad or Where ever your going to start the assign this

```
 patternColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]
```

This will resolve your memory issues and below code willhelp you

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), patternColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I used this line of code previously but not filled my exact pattern.I want pattern like following url: "http://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/225074_513694782028209_1761743512_n.jpg" Previous was just filled UIView not control Brush Flow so how to Controlling of brush flow and and filled pattern For More you can see Paint Gallery app for using of brush flow and patten.

Comment: ImagePattern Url :[link](http://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/225074_513694782028209_1761743512_n.jpg)\n Paint Gallery app :[link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paint-gallery/id445258482?mt=8)

Comment: I used the same code and was able to do the same you can go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053563/how-to-unerase-the-erased-uiimage

Comment: I am find in apple to drawin .You can also check it is good to Core Graphics Layer Drawing [link]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH219-TPXREF101